# redirection from one user control to another user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, response.redirect, server.transfer

I have a usercontrol.ascx in a aspx page. And in my user control I have a button click event, and I need to open another user control from this button click. Please give me some suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visible property. Let's call the user control with the button ucControl1 and the other ucControl2.

```
// code-behind of ucControl1
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
    ucControl2.Visible = false;
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucControl2.Visible = true;
}
```